# How do I access a custom Asset field within an Assets field?

Tags: assets

I want to setup a custom field to assign a URL for an image.  On the front end I want to output the image and then wrap it in a URL. I've setup a field called 'logoURL' but not sure how to access that data.  What I have isn't working and I've tried several variations.

```
{% set logo = { width: 175, height: 120, mode: 'fit' } %}

{% for image in entry.logos %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ logos.logoURL }}"><img src="{{ image.getUrl(logo) }}" height="{{ image.getHeight(logo) }}" width="{{ image.getWidth(logo) }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"></a>          
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You’re close. When you do this:

```twig
{% for image in entry.logos %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

The code within the for-loop will be repeated for each asset that was assigned to your `entry.logos` field. Each time, the `image` variable will be assigned the current asset.

So, if you want to access a field that is *on the asset* (e.g. your `logoUrl` field), you would access that via `image.logoUrl` rather than `logos.logoUrl`. (You don’t actually have a variable named `logos`, so if you have [Dev Mode](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/dev-mode) enabled, that template would be giving you an error about that.)

```twig
{% set logo = { width: 175, height: 120, mode: 'fit' } %}

{% for image in entry.logos %}
    <li><a href="{{ image.logoURL }}"><img src="{{ image.getUrl(logo) }}" height="{{ image.getHeight(logo) }}" width="{{ image.getWidth(logo) }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, Brandon! That worked. I thought I had tried that variation but alas. We're on our 7th Craft license and loving it.

Comment: @David Glad to hear that! :)